# NestJS TypeORM - Why does a Unique constraint in an entity throw an exception and crash the app

Tags: unique, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity described as

```
export class TeamEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  readonly id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  readonly createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  @Unique('Duplicate name', ['name'])
  name: string;
}
```

When trying to add a record for the first time to the database the record is inserted as expected. When that same record is attempted to be inserted again, the unique constraint is not met and as expected the record is not inserted.

The problem is that the whole app crashes when this constraint is not met and I have to restart the app in order to get it back online again.

A strange exception to this rule is that when a `console.log()` is present anywhere in the execution path the application does not crash and the correct error message is thrown and the app continues.

Is there a reason the app doesn't crash when there is a `console.log()` present? And if so, how do I stop the app from crashing when I remove this line?

Comment: Sounds like a heisenbug! :-O Can you add the code of your service? Is it called by a controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Insert ignore` for this issue

```
await getManager()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .insert()
      .orIgnore(true)
      .into(TeamEntity)
      .values({name: 'John'})
      .execute();
```